# Windows Sidebar - Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, slideshow, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have created a **Windows Sidebar Countdown gadget** where there is a PIC in the BG and below it there's that countdown when finished it shows a text message , Now what I want to do is that I want to add a slideshow in the BG ( of 3 to 4 images) ... So experts please guide me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setTimeout method from javascript, and after every few seconds change the background image in the body.

document.body.background = "image.gif"

eg.

setTimeout('changeImage(1)',1000);

function changeImage(i)
{
  if i == 4 return;

document.body.background = 'image'+i+'.gif';
  setTimeout('changeImage('+(i+1)+')',1000);
}

You should have the images image1.gif, image2.gif and so on in the same folder as your gadget.html